# My hasMany in laravel response null, my model its correct

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem my has many relation response null.
this is my model

```
    class Diskusi extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tbl_diskusi';

    protected $hidden = [
        'topic'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id_user');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function pets_category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(PetsCategory::class);
    }
}
```

this is my another model

```
    class PetsCategory extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'tbl_pets_category';

    public function diskusi(){
        return $this->hasMany(Diskusi::class,'id_pets_category');
    }

}
```

and another

```
    class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'tbl_category';

    public function diskusi(){
        return $this->hasMany(Diskusi::class,'id_category');
    }
}
```

and this is my migration for Diskusi

```
    class CreateTblDiskusi extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbl_diskusi', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('content');
            $table->string('topic');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_user');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_category');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_pets_category');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')
            ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('id_category')->references('id')
            ->on('tbl_category')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('id_pets_category')->references('id')
            ->on('tbl_pets_category')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_diskusi');
    }
}
```

the condition is
i want my Diskusi have one category, and one pets_category

but when i create Diskusi like this

```
    public function create(Request $request)
{
    $diskusi = new Diskusi;
    $diskusi->title = $request->title;
    $diskusi->content = $request->content;
    $diskusi->topic = $request->topic;
    $diskusi->id_user = Auth::user()->id;
    $diskusi->id_category = $request->id_category;
    $diskusi->id_pets_category = $request->id_pets_category;


    if ($request->photo != ''){
        foreach ($request->photo as $itemPhoto) {
            # code...
            $photo = new Photo;

            $rand = $this->generateRandomString() . 'jpg';
            //taroh foto di server
            // file_put_contents('storage/photo/diskusi/' . $rand , base64_decode($request->photo));
            $photo->path_photo = $rand;
            $photo->save();
        }
    }
    $diskusi->save();
    $diskusi->user;
    $diskusi->category;
    $diskusi->pets_category;

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'posted',
        'post' => $diskusi
    ]);

}
```

the response like this
[image]

please help me, i tried with many tutorial relational laravel but it's not working for me. i dont know where my false, please tell me my false.

*note: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to define your foreign key in relationship.

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'id_category','id');
}

public function pets_category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(PetsCategory::class,'id_pets_category','id');
}
```

If you don't pass the foreign key then by default it judges `'category_id'` or `'pets_category_id'` but you've given `id_category` and `id_pets_category`